# Memory allocation and solve linear systems in Julia

Tags: memory, julia, linear-algebra

I'm using Julia 1.5.0. Consider the following code:

```
using LinearAlgebra
using Distributions
using BenchmarkTools

function solve_b!(A, tol_iters)
    b   = [1.0 2.0]'
    luA = lu!(A)
    x   = [0.0; 0.0]
    for i =1:tol_iters
        A[1,1] += 0.001
        A[2,2] += 0.001
        luA = lu!(A)
        ldiv!(x, luA, b)
    end
end

A = rand(2,2)
solve_b!(A, 1000)
```

If I run this with `julia --track-allocation=user`, I see that most of the memory allocation comes from `b   = [1.0 2.0]'` and `x   = [0.0; 0.0]`. That is, when I see the .mem file, I see the following:

> ```
>    96     b   = [1.0 2.0]'
>     0     luA = lu!(A)
>    96     x   = [0.0; 0.0]
> ```

The memory allocation increases as I increase `tol_iters`.
Can someone explain why? I'm using `lu!` and `ldiv!`, so I would expect the update to be *in-place*. Therefore there should not be any additional memory allocation associated with the number of iterations.

Comment: `lu!` does allocate, it only promises to reduce the amount of allocations by using `A` to perform internal computations.

Comment: @BogumiłKamiński So there is no way to improve this function? I must allocate if I solve linear systems?

Comment: I think the usual way to do this is to solve the problem once, and then use an update formula like [this one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sherman%E2%80%93Morrison_formula).

Comment: See also here: https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/72cf/f71a6026c15102d1c23d8c429ca60fe2d048.pdf.

Comment: @phipsgabler In my actual code, the matrix changes in a more complicated way than the sample code. The question is more about memory allocation of Julia when solving linear systems.